# How do I bulk edit the default application for many file types in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, mime-types

Last year I test drove Lapce & somehow set it to be the default application for over 100 source file types. I don't remember how I did this, but the XFCE Default Applications program tells me so. Uninstalling Lapce bumped the default application to Emacs for these filetypes. Is there a way to set the default application to Neovim (e.g.) for all these filetypes at once? I'm running Arch and Linux kernel 6.7.0.

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023143/349837). Please add the output of `grep -i Lapce /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`. Probably you could just `sed -i` to search/replace in-place. Of course, always run a backup before.

Comment: There's no `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` on my laptop.

Comment: Interesting! That file is from `desktop-file-utils` package on Debian/Ubuntu ([here](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/desktop-file-utils/) on Arch), from [Freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils)

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with that and see if I can get what I want out of it.

Comment: That package is already installed. I tried reinstalling it, but still no `defaults.list`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check ~/.config/mimeapps.list ; chances are, there's still a lot of mappings to `emacs.desktop`.

Find a type where you manually changed the program to open that type to your neovim frontend; use that `something.desktop` to replace `emacs.desktop` in all instances.

Comment: There are no mappings to `emacs.desktop` in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: interesting! Is that also the case for ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list?

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my laptop.

Comment: it doesn't have to; that would only exist if your user added programs of his own and then selected these to open a file type. That's fine! 

So, then it's kind of down to simply adding the file mappings you want (en masse) to ~/.config/mimeapps.list, because your system seems to default to emacs system-wide.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there's no obvious solution to the "bulk" component of my question; i.e. looks like I'll have to associate them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make system wide changes then have a look at `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

In my case, on [Linux Mint 21.3 "Virginia" Xfce Edition](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=313), I had different browsers opening links and files depending on where I was calling them from. For instance when clicking a **URL** in terminal it would open *firefox*, when double-clicking a file with an **.html** or **.htm** extension from *thunar* it would open *google chrome* and when clicking a URL/link within a desktop app it would open *chromium* which I had set as my default browser.

I'm no expert but for me editing `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` allowed me to change the "*mime type to application*" associations for all declared mime types that had a line entry in the defaults.list file, rather than just for one app for the current user when editing either of the `mimeapps.list` files found at:

```
.local/share/applications/
~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

I changed all the `firefox.dektop` and `google-chrome.desktop` entries to `chromium-browser.desktop`.

A simple `sed` replace, or any other editor you prefer to do a search/replace with, is the simplest and quickest method:
`sed s/google\-chrome/chromium\-browser/g /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

**Note**:
Using the command `locate defaults.list`, I found a few `defaults.list` files on my system:

```
/etc/gnome/defaults.list
/etc/xfce4/defaults.list
/home/$USER/defaults.list
/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/xfce4/applications/defaults.list
```

I don't know if I could have achieved the same result just for my username (which I think would be a better option) by editing one of the other `defaults.list` files listed above. With any luck someone more knowledgeable than me will jump in and make the correct assertions.

**FYI**:
The contents of my `/home/$USER/defaults.list` looks very similar to the contents of `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

It's easy enough to check using `diff`
`sudo diff /home/$USER/defaults.list /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

Comment: P.S. you need to edit the file as root. i.e. `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

Comment: My system lacks `defaults.list`, although it does have `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, which wasn't causing a problem. Making some edits to `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` fixes it, although I think this file is managed by `desktop-file-utils`, so I don't expect my edits to necessarily stick.

Comment: @GarrigusCarraig I'm interested in what your "system" is? and I suspect you're correct about ```/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache``` in that it will likely be modified automagically just by looking at its name ```.cache```, but I couldn't tell you if it's managed by ```desktop-file-utils``` or otherwise. As I stated, I'm no expert. A little research would yield the answer.
Maybe if you search ur "system" for all ```mimeapps.list``` files it would give you a clue.
One of the joys (or banes) of linux is that there is a wealth of info out there and there's always the option to RTFM

Comment: @GarrigusCarraig
I think this is the crux of the matter =>

https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/shared-mime-info/update-mime-database.1.en.html

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/desktop-file-utils/update-desktop-database.1.en.html

Comment: \["System" == operating system (Arch Linux) plus whatever packages I have installed.\] `update-desktop-database` does seem to edit `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. I thought there might be a straightforward answer to this (for me) relatively inconsequential question, but it is indeed time to RTFM.

Comment: I wonder if this helps => https://forum.zorin.com/t/how-to-set-default-applications-in-xfce/10612